# Read Weight from Weigh Bridge using serial port in C# not working

Tags: c#

I have written web service to get the weight from weigh bridge using serial port. but some times it is not getting full value
Ex: if the weight is 390 kg, some times it will fetch 39 or 0, or 390 or 9

we are using another software called hyper terminal, there it is fetching value correctly.

weight is not fluctuating in weigh bridge.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Ports;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Services;
    
    namespace WeighBridgeWS
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for WeighBridge
        /// </summary>
        [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
        public class WeighBridge : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {
            public static string weightRead { get; set; }
            public WeighBridge()
            {
    
                //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
                //InitializeComponent(); 
               // weightRead = "10000";
            }
            [WebMethod]
            #region || ReadWeight ||
            public string ReadWeight()
            {
                try
                {
                    string PortNo = "COM1";
                    SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort(PortNo);
    
                    mySerialPort.BaudRate = 2400;
                    mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.Even;
                    mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                    mySerialPort.DataBits = 7;
                    mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    
                    mySerialPort.DataReceived += new   SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
                    mySerialPort.Open();
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    mySerialPort.Close();
    
                    return weightRead;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ExceptionLogging.SendErrorToText(ex); 
                    return "";
                }
    
            }
            #endregion
    
            #region || ReadWeight ||
            public static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
                sp.ReadTimeout = 5000;
                sp.WriteTimeout = 5000;
                if (!sp.IsOpen)
                    sp.Open();
                weightRead = sp.ReadExisting();
                if (sp.IsOpen)
                    sp.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ExceptionLogging.SendErrorToText(ex);               
                }
    
            }
            #endregion
    
           
        }
    }
```

I tried another method using read method instated of read existing

```
    int bytesToRead = 10; // Change this to the number of bytes you want to read
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
    int bytesRead = sp.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
    
    // Process and handle the received data
    weightRead = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

still it is not working

Comment: What does it do?  "not working" is not very helpful.

Comment: You need to set the `ReadTimeout` and `WriteTimeout` before you open the port.  As it is, your `DataReceivedHandler` might get called with a partial transfer.